# Is it possible to Base64 encode a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, base64

I was looking to base64 encode a portion of my chrome extension. However, it did not work when I tried to test it. (The extension works fine when not encoded).

Is it possible to Base64 encode a portion of javascript for use in a Chrome extension? If so, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The global [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.atob) method can be used to decode base64 strings (and [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.btoa) can be used to encode a string as base64). After decoding a string `eval` can be used to parse the string as code, and run it.

For example, here's a one-liner to print the ID of the current extension:

```
alert(eval(atob('Y2hyb21lLmkxOG4uZ2V0TWVzc2FnZSgnQEBleHRlbnNpb25faWQnKQ==')));
```

#### Explanation

I generated the previous base64 string by typing `btoa("chrome.i18n.getMessage('@@extension_id')")` in the JavaScript console. You're free to use any other method (such as the [base64 command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/base64)). Here's the full breakdown of the previous one-liner.

```
alert(eval(atob(btoa("chrome.i18n.getMessage('@@extension_id')")));
//atob decodes from base64, btoa encodes to base64, so they cancel out each other
alert(eval(          "chrome.i18n.getMessage('@@extension_id')" ));
//eval parses the string as code, so we get
alert(                chrome.i18n.getMessage('@@extension_id')   );
```

#### Content security policy

If you want to use this method in the extension's process (e.g. [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) / [popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html) page), the [Content Security policy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) needs to be adjusted. By default, code generation from strings is forbidden. To override this default policy, add the following entry to the manifest file:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

Comment: Would this make all users need to re-enable the extension? Last time when I changed the Permissions, I lost 1/3 of my users in one day. Because since Google disables the extension, it gives a popup "this user added these permissions" warning, even though it was less permissions, not more. So a lot of users thought that it was scary and decided to uninstall. Would I have to worry about that when changing the security policy like this?

Comment: The CSP does not affect permission warnings.

Comment: Ok thanks. Only problem is this appears to be in an alert box aka popup window; but I need it to run in the background automatically within the chrome extension and it needs to be instantaneous.

Comment: @gameaddict The `alert` box was merely an example. You can base64-encode your whole JavaScript file, and wrap the result in `eval(atob("...base64 string..."));`

Comment: Just want to follow up that I did use this and it worked very well. FYI. And it still works now in 2016.